# Compare decimal number and without decimal number data With decimal value

Tags: java

I don't know how to do comparison between numbers in below scenario.

In request, I'll get some value `grossAmount=1` and same data will be saved to as 1.00.

But again I may get same request `grossAmount=1.0`(request manually updated).

Theoretically, `grossAmount=1`, `grossAmount=1.0` and `grossAmount=1.00` all are equal.

Can someone help me with this please? (DB can't be modified)

I need to compare in java

Comment: Whats the code you are using?

What are the number classes you are using?

Comment: Easy thing will be as and when you get the data , you know you are storing it is as Decimal in the DB , so you can convert the data from int to double , providing the exact precision .

Comment: Actually, I dont know how to compare. I was just using splitting with **.** and trying. So that's the best practice.

Comment: But the problem is , I may get 1.0 or 1.00 or 1. If i i always get 1, then convert that to double and compare

Comment: No you should not do that , it is not good practice to compare by splitting

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, Thank you. I got it now. Your previous comments helped me

Comment: `String dbValue = "1.00";
        String dennis = "1.00";
        double f = Double.parseDouble(dennis);
        System.out.println(f);
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", new BigDecimal(f)));

        if(String.format("%.2f", new BigDecimal(f)).equals(dbValue)){
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }` will solve my problem

Comment: @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi, While in this particular case double does the job, in general double is not precise and should not be used when precision is needed. The precise types in Java are BigDecimal, BigInteger, long, int and byte. For a general answer to this question I would have preferred BigDecimal.

Comment: Sure @Jonathan noted , thanks you for sharing the information .